# Render time: Baking particle system

Tags: particles, eevee-render-engine, baking

In my scene I have 4 particle system (emitters to simulates smoke with curve fields).
I am using Eevee.
Render time for 1 frame without the emitters rendered: 1 second.
With the emitters rendered: 26 seconds.
I so decided to bake the simulation for better performance during rendering (in case I will need to adjust other stuff and re run the render).
But even after baking the rendering time stays the same, 26 seconds, so I am not sure I am doing things right.
After the baking process all the particle settings are grayed out (as meant to be) for all the 4 emitters. I used the 'bake all dynamics'.
So why is the render time not improving? It feels like it is calculating as if the bake was not there.

Thanks!

Comment: Simply because it is render time of particles and not simulation calculation? Why there is not a progress in time for baked? Probably there is not any advantage of bake because it is using cached sim, so there is not any recalculation of sim.

Comment: I see. It makes sense. I so replaced the metaball I was using with a subdiv cube and it got better. Thanks

Comment: Mark as answered if you want. I still have no access to that

Comment: Baking a simulation only ensures that during rendering there is no glitch in the simulation from of unclear particle states due to unfinished simulation calculations etc.  because of the fact they are not calculated during redering. So baking or not has absolutely nothing to do with render time, what has an influence is the number of particles and therefore the amount of shaded surfaces the render engine has to calculate. (By the way, only answers can be marked as accepted answers, not a question or a comment.)